# Comma seperated text field into a HTML ol

Tags: 7

I have created a custom content type and one of the fields will be a texfield with values separated by a comma e.g.

value 1, value 2, value 3

I want to then display this as an unordered list in the output.

Can anyone help with how this can be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [hook_node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) like this

```
function hook_node_view($node, $view_mode) {
  // explode the field contents with comma
  // replace the content with your exploded value.
  $node->content['yourfield'] = 'YOUR_EXPLODED_VALUE';
}
```

[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)